# how to invoke sudo su - user from python code (without password)? Tried -> stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sudo su - user')

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a script to execute some operation in multiple server.
Where i used to login in server using 1 account, later need to do sudo to switch the account, that is not working.

Tried below cmd

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sudo su - user')
```

Getting below error
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sudo su - user')
                                                             ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

```
.......

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient() `ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())`
ssh.connect(host,username=uname,password=pwd)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("hostname")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sudo su - user')
.....
```

Post ssh connection my script should switch the user.
For e.x-> server abc.com , uname = abhi, password = pwd, user = xyz

Than output will be

```
login as: abhi
abhi@abc.com's password:
Last login: Thu Apr  4 01:49:06 2019 from abc.com
[abhi@abc.com ~]$ sudo su - xyz
Last login: Thu Apr  4 06:38:36 CDT 2019 on pts/6
[xyz@abc.com ~]$
```

Comment: What;s the error? The TabError? That's formatting in your file

Comment: Thanks its working fine, after removing 1 extra space from code thats creating issue :(